# C++ & Boost: How do I convert a dynamic bitset to a string?

Tags: c++, boost

So, the documentation says this:

```
template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Block, typename Alloc>
basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& os, const dynamic_bitset<Block, Alloc>& b)
```

Effects: Inserts a textual representation of b into the stream os (highest bit first). Informally, the output is the same as doing

```
std::basic_string<Char, Traits> s;
boost::to_string(x, s):
os << s;
```

which I don't understand at all.

Here is what I have

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit_value(Config::HASH_WIDTH_IN_BITS, hash_value);
string buffer = bit_value.to_string();
```

Which doesn't work, cause dynamic bitset has no member .to_string();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`to_string` is a free function in the `boost` namespace, not a member function.

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit_value(Config::HASH_WIDTH_IN_BITS, hash_value);
string buffer;
to_string(bit_value, buffer);
// here buffer contains the string representation of bit_value.
```

Comment: Which header should be included?

Comment: `boost::dynamic_bitset` is defined in boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp